# Minimal F# example to watch the Windows security Event Log

Tags: f#, event-log

This never prints any events to the console (after "listening for new security events..."), though when I fire up the Event Viewer app it shows security events coming in.  Thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Security.Principal
open System.Threading

let logName = "security"

let DumpEventLog desc =
  use log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog (logName, desc)
  log.EnableRaisingEvents <- true;
  printfn "listening for new security events...";
  log.EntryWritten.Add (fun ent ->
    let ent = ent.Entry in
    printfn "entry written: %d %s %s" ent.InstanceId (ent.TimeGenerated.ToString())
      ent.Message);
  
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _argv =
  let isAdministrator =
    let id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent () in
    let p = WindowsPrincipal id in
    p.IsInRole WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator
  in
  let () =
    if not isAdministrator
    then printfn "need admin privs to run!"
    else DumpEventLog "."
  in
  while true do
    Thread.Sleep 5000
  done;
  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the way your program is written. For example, when DumpEventLog() exits, the log is disposed - but then the program sleeps for five seconds. I don't see how it would catch an event in that state.

This works for me:

```
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _argv =
    use log = new EventLog ("security", ".")
    log.EnableRaisingEvents <- true
    printfn "listening for new security events..."

    log.EntryWritten.Add (fun e -> 
        printfn "Entry written: %d %O %s" e.Entry.InstanceId e.Entry.TimeGenerated e.Entry.Message)

    Thread.Sleep Timeout.Infinite
    
    0
```